# How to call more than one web services in same activity in android

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask, callback

hi i am calling two web services at one by one in same common Asyntask (which is using as other class )using one callback which have been placed in onPostExecute method and try to update UI by using custom adapter because i will get one response from first web service and try to put value for second web service hit .but my problem is callback called when i hit my first web service only and which doesn't call again for second web service hit so that i couldn't able update my UI by using of adapter. getting Null pointer exception.

Please any body give me a good suggestion for call more than one web service in same activity using same  asyntask.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask by default executes in a serial queue (one after another).
Example :

```
new ExampleAsynTask().execute(url1,url2);
```